# Java TCP server class abstraction

Tags: java, serversocket, ioexception, abstraction

For learning purposes, I'm writing a Java TCP server. This is being wrapped into its own class as `SyteTCPServer`, which uses `ServerSocket` to handle connection logic. This is for a school project where good code practices are very important.

The reason it's being put in its own class is because there is a specific application-level protocol. The class is part of a larger project.

When googling, I only found people putting all the `ServerSocket` and its accompanying logic directly inside the main method. I'm not sure that's the way to go when it comes to OOP?

My `SyteTCPServer` has a simple `Start()` and `Stop()` method, it hides the implementation of using a `ServerSocket`, handling clients, etc..

However, I'm a bit stumped because with a lot of the networking functions, IntelliJ warns me to catch IOExceptions. Accepting a client could throw an IOException, so could getting the output stream of said client, so could `writeBytes`,.. you get my point.

In the context of abstraction, how do I best go about these exceptions? Do I write a `throws IOException` next to the method, making the higher-up code `try...catch` the `SyteTCPServer.Start`?

Also, should the whole server stop must any exceptions occur, or do I "hide" the fact that one of the clients did not connect properly? Or perhaps, should I fire an event when a client failed to connect? I really don't know..

I also avoid writing output when an exception occurs like the plague because of UI/core code separation.

I hope these aren't too many questions in one.

Here's an example of the start method I have, with throws IOException:

```
public void Start() throws IOException {
    this.listenSocket = new ServerSocket(this.port);

    Listen();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's important that you differentiate between different IOExceptions you might receive. For example, is it an exception on creating a new connection or one while the connection was already established, is it a somewhat expected error or not? The easiest way for this is to just read the [documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) and handle the error according to what exactly is happening:

For constructing a server socket:

> public ServerSocket(int port) throws IOException
>
> - IOException - if an I/O error occurs when opening the socket.
> - SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its checkListen method doesn't allow the operation.
> - IllegalArgumentException - if the port parameter is outside the specified range of valid port values, which is between 0 and 65535, inclusive.

For accepting a connection:

> public Socket accept() throws IOException
>
> - IOException - if an I/O error occurs when waiting for a connection.
> - SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its checkAccept method doesn't allow the operation.
> - SocketTimeoutException - if a timeout was previously set with setSoTimeout and the timeout has been reached.
> - IllegalBlockingModeException - if this socket has an associated channel, the channel is in non-blocking mode, and there is no connection ready to be accepted

And so on.

About where to catch the exception(s): this also depends on what you want your server to do in specific cases. But in general, catch 'expected' errors and handle them there and then, but throw the non-intentional errors to a higher level.

What I mean by this:

```
public void foo() throws IOException {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Port is in use -> perhaps retry on another port
        // If things fail, throw exception anyway
    } finally {
        if (!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // This exception is to be taken care of internally, not thrown
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that this is applicable not only for server-side, but for client-side as well.

Good luck writing your server!

Answer (score 1):

> I only found people putting all the ServerSocket and its accompanying
>   logic directly inside the main method. I'm not sure that's the way to
>   go when it comes to OOP?

Putting all the `ServerSocket` creation code and its subsequent logic like accepting, handling and read/write to the client in a `main()` method directly is definitely not a good OOP practice.

With OOP, we should think from a perspective of objects and how these objects interact with each other to meet the desired functionality. And each object encapsulates a distinct responsibility.

> Accepting a client could throw an IOException, so could getting the
>   output stream of said client, so could writeBytes,.. you get my point.
>
> In the context of abstraction, how do I best go about these
>   exceptions? Do I write a throws IOException next to the method, making
>   the higher-up code try...catch the SyteTCPServer.Start?

Few best practices I can highlight

- Don't forget to log the exception with with all the necessary information as it forms indispensable tool later for debugging and other improvements.
- Don't catch the same exception with multiple try/catch along the flow.
- Don't swallow the exceptions after catching it and do rethrow them, unless it is really not needed.
- Finally, how to handle an exception also depends on whether it is recoverable exception or not. If not recoverable log the exception, clean up the resources. If recoverable log the exception and follow the steps to recover from exception. And the best guide here is javadoc for that API.

> Also, should the whole server stop must any exceptions occur, or do I
>   "hide" the fact that one of the clients did not connect properly? Or
>   perhaps, should I fire an event when a client failed to connect?

As you go along implementing the code, I am sure you will find even more classes, one of them could be, to handle each client connection request in a separate thread, say `ClientConnectionHandler` object (Thread) so that other clients are not blocked. And so each client connection would become an independent thread of execution.

With this design, if the exception is specific to that client connection there is no need to bring down the entire server. Just terminating that client thread and cleaning the up resources should suffice.